# Downloading and loading an image into a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I have a little problem with downloading an image from google using VB.net

now, here's the thing:

if i use this code to download the file, then VB will download the file, but it's only 1 kb. However, the images 'im trying to download are between 60 and 120 kb.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(StrUrl, StrPath & "Photo.jpg")
```

conclusion: can't use this downloaded file in a PictureBox.

So, I tried downloading using the webclient, which i did as follows:

```
Dim WbClient As New WebClient
        WbClient.DownloadFile(StrUrl, StrPath & "Photo.jpg")
        WbClient.Dispose()
```

So this downloaded file is the actual size of the image. BUT:
when i want to load this into a PictureBox, it wouldn't load. Even when I try to open it with my pictureviewer from windonws, it doesn't open neighter.

(Note that if I download the images manually, it works fine)

then there's just one more thing:
I alos tried to load the images in two different ways into the picturebox.
and i did it like so:

way 1:

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = StrPath & "Photo.jpg"
```

way 2:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(StrPath & "Photo.jpg")
```

But no success....

Anyone of you guys can help me? cuz I am really getting frustrated about it :(

thanks!

Comment: It is a URL to a picture on the web. For example:
https://www.google.be/imgres?imgurl=http://be.foto.com/images/newsite/menu/illu/gift-new.jpg&imgrefurl=http://be.foto.com/nl/&h=200&w=248&tbnid=3rUpkuPTG0EOtM:&docid=kFu5fqZKU_3dkM&ei=kRZmVoyrOYH-aa3eidgC&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjMt5Hv88rJAhUBfxoKHS1vAisQMwg0KAAwAA

Comment: You cannot just use the Google link. You need to use the direct link that leads directly to the image, or else you will download a web page instead (which is probably why you cannot view the download even in Windows Picture Viewer). Press the `View image` (or whatever it's called) button on Google, and use that link instead.

Comment: Owh, you are right. Stupid me. Guess i have to take a break sometime. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hmmm. I jut said that too early I guess. Still same problem if i download using the real Image Url.
I cannot open/display/load the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the file, unless you need it for something else:

```
Using wc As New WebClient()
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(wc.OpenRead(StrUrl))
End Using
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response.
I only Just cannot use your solution because:

i need to download, like 20 images and i'm storing them into different directories. 

then i've listed those directories into a ListBox. So when i Click a dirctory in my listbox, the program has to load the image thats inside the directory.

Comment: So that would be in the "you need it for something else" category.